# Stacked bar chart does not show bar values for time series X axis - ReactJS Recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have some JSON data which is going to be displayed in a Stacked Bar chart using RechartJS in a ReactJS application.

I use `type="number"` for the X axis to dispaly the data in a time series, but here's how the chart is displayed:

[image]

As you can see: there is data but bars does not get displayed, using `type="category"` for the X axis will show the bars, but that wont provide a way to show dates with empty data unless those dates got filled in the JSON.

The data is an array of objects that look like this:

```
    [
      {
        "date": 1632200400000,
        "Banana": 4,
        "Apples": 15,
        "Oranges": 12,
        "Strawberry": 10,
        "BlueBerries": 8,
        "Cherries": 8,
        "Mango": 2,
        "Kiwi": 4,
        "Lemon": 4,
        "Grapes": 6
      },
      ...
    ]
```

Also there is an array of items for the bars:

```
[
  "Banana",
  "Apples",
  "Oranges",
  "Strawberry",
  "BlueBerries",
  "Cherries",
  "Mango",
  "Kiwi",
  "Lemon",
  "Grapes"
]
```

The code looks like this:

```
<BarChart data={data} width={600} height={300}>
  <XAxis
    dataKey="date"
    domain={["dataMin", "dataMax"]}
    padding={{ left: 32, right: 32 }}
    type="number"
    interval={0}
    tickFormatter={(time) => format(new Date(time), "HH:mm")}
  />
  <YAxis width={100} orientation="left" />

  {items.map((itemName) => (
    <Bar
      barSize={20}
      dataKey={itemName}
      stackId="a"
      fill={generateColor()}
    />
  ))}

  <CartesianGrid />
  <Tooltip />
  <Legend />
</BarChart>
```

Here you can find the codesandbox for the code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-stackbar-time-series-3z8s5

Comment: Will you be plotting a date other than the one that exists in JSON? If you are plotting any date then you will at least add an object with no details, right?

Comment: @MehulThakkar This is what should be done if I used type="category" in X axis, but I must not do it like this because of some analytic reasons.

Using type="number" will provide an excellent way to show data with dates that does not exist (in a domain you provide), just by providing `domain` and `ticks` props to the X axis

Comment: @MehulThakkar but as you can see that bars does not show when providing `type="number"`

Comment: may this [issue](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1137) help you?